# Problem with high recursion depth in .NET DataContract serializer with complex project hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I actually have a problem with .NET DataContract serialization trying to serialize a large project. The process results in a StackOverflowException at recursion depth ~5500.

It's not just because the project has many elements (around 6 million). The high recursion depth is a result of some of our objects having a cross-reference to other elements in the hierarchy.

Simple example:
Assume we want to serialize object A with child objects B, C, D, E, F. This would result in recursion depth 2 for the serialized object tree.

But if each object itself references every other child object, we would result in resursion depth 6, because the serializer walks along A=>B=>C=>D=>E=>F instead of returning to A after each child.

Is there any way to control the .NET DataContract serializer in a way that it does NOT follow specific cross-references to prevent that kind of deep recursion? I need to define that it is not required to go from B to C to D and so on, because it can reach C, D, E, F from A.

"IsReference" is not a solution for this, because that only helps, when objects are already known. But in my case the serializer does not know "C" yet when serializing "B".

Using "Order" on DataMembers does not help, too.

Two possible solutions I currently have are:
1.) Replace cross-references with the ID of the target before serializing and restore the cross-references after deserializing again by searching the objects with the serialized ID.
2.) Move cross-reference information of all objects to a sepearate child element G under A and set G to the highest "Order" so that it is serialized at last element. That way elements B to F are serialized from root element A without being connected to each other. And when the serializer finally reaches element G all objects are already known and only referenced.

But these "solutions" require me to change the object model. It would be best to have the serializer work with the current object model.

Comment: I'm guessing the difficulty with changing the model is due to all the existing code referencing it.  If this is the case, why not create an entirely new DTO model which is the thing that is actually forming the datacontract and design this with the serialisation in mind?  Then you can simply map your internal data to the external one for these operations.  I typically do a similar thing with API projects - the classes which are externally exposed may appear very similar (or maybe even identical) to the internal DB model classes, but they aren't the same.

Comment: To expand on @GPW's advice, it is usually a good idea to separate the in-memory runtime object model and the persistence object model for the very reason you are now asking about, the in-memory model doesn't easily lend itself to serialization. You *will* need to store some form of identity in your persisted objects, otherwise if you have A contains B contains C, and A contains D contains C (same instance as B contains), you want to avoid deserialization creating 2 C instances.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Avoiding serializing/deserializing 2 C instances is done by the serializer itself. If class C has the DataContract IsReference=true attribute, it is automatically assigned an ID and only serialized once. The next time it appears in the object tree, only the reference is serialized referring to the original instance.

Comment: @GPW It is difficult to change due to many reasons. Yes all the existing code is one reason due to the fact that it is a large project. Changing the object model to work better with the serializer would be a project for future versions. But such large changes could not be applied/patched on released versions. For this case the only solution would be to "guide" the serializer a better way. :-)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change your object model. I'm suggesting you create a *second* object model to fulfill the immediate needs of the external.contract. 
Otherwise the problem you end up with is bi-directional; you end up having things exposed in the contract (such as unique ids), and/or you end up having to hack your persistence model with classes/attributes/etc which aren't necessary for the persistence side and are only there for the contract. You also then end up in a situation where you can't easily change either the external contract or the persistence model as something breaks.

Comment: My mistake, I read it as a recursion problem, but I understand now what the problem is. I don't think you can get by without changing the object model, or temporarily changing the data to break some of the long chains of references.